# mean value theorem( integral over an integral)

Tags: calculus, average

I have a question which has been driving me crazy for a while now. I've been googling to find an answer but with no success.

I am aware of the "Mean Value Theorem" for integrals but have seen in some physics books that the mean value is expressed in the form : $F_{Mean}=\frac{\int f(x) dx}{\int dx}$ (not exactly but similarly).

Also, the other day I was discussing "particle size distribution" with my supervisor and he said the average particle size that follows the following distribution $N=C\int_{r_0}^{r_1} r^{-q}$ can be found by: $$<r>=\frac{\int N (r) . r dr}{\int N(r) dr}$$

Could anyone explain where does the notion of "integral division: come from? What is it called?I've been googling different keywords to read on the topic but no success. I can see the similarity between $F_{Mean}=\frac{\int f(x) dx}{\int_a^b dx}$ and $F_{Mean}=\frac{1}{(b-a)}\int f(x) dx$ but in text books I have only seen the latter notion of the MVT. Are those the same thing? How about the equation for the average particle size?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is then issue here? When you evaluate those integrals you get a real number, which you can then divide. The two forms of the MVT you have cited are equivalent. $\int_a^b dx $ is the same as $b-a$, since the anti derivative of $1$ is $x$. Can you clarify your confusion if at all possible?

Comment: @Gabe The confusion comes from the fact that I've never seen the notion $\frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{\int_a^b dx}$ in classical calculus books, nor on the web. Can you point to source where this notation is discussed and has been used?

Comment: It is not so much a question of notation as it is a question of what the actual mathematical objects are. When you evaluate the integral in the numerator and in the denominator, you get real numbers. You can then divide those as usual. The notation means exactly the same as when you write $a/b$.